# Unable to inherit QWeb Template of PoS module in Odoo

Tags: inheritance, odoo

I am very new to Odoo. I have been working on the PoS module and I need to change the UI interface of the PoS module. The screen I need to modify is the payment screen which shows the productlist, the calculator view for payment and the validate button.

I know I need to inherit the qweb template of PoS and use that. But I am unable to inherit that. This is because the PoS template which displays the elements on PoS UI is pos.xml and there are only t-tags inside it without any particular template record with identified template id. I tried to make a simple change by using the following code:

```
  <template id="payment_screen">
            <t t-extend="PaymentScreenWidget">
                <t t-jquery="div.pos-payment-container" t-operation="after">
                    <div>
                       Payment Screen Modified
                    </div>  
                </t>
            </t>
</template>
```

But it does not work. I am sure I must be doing some mistake here. I want someone to correct me at this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@John

Try this

```
            <t t-extend="PaymentScreenWidget">
                <t t-jquery="div.pos-payment-container" t-operation="after">
                    <div>
                       Payment Screen Modified
                    </div>  
                </t>
            </t>
```

Don't give the **`<template id="payment_screen">`**. It works without that.